# Where to include common scripts

Tags: 8, theming

I am looking at adding a new javascript library to drupal 8. I want the ability to call this library from other modules / libraries.

The way WordPress does this is by the use of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Using a common library would make sure that my library is loading just once.

An existing implementation of this in drupal is the way you can add dependencies into your the yml files

```
js:
 dependencies:
  - core/jquery
```

Is there a way I can add my own javascript library as the dependency that can be used throughout my drupal instance (all modules and themes should be able to use this as a dependency)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme it explains it really well.

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamic libraries as shared libraries, check the following

[hook_library_info_build() for dynamic library definitions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2374649)

You can add javascript libraries to a theme like the following

[Adding Javascript to a D8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#external)

You can add javascript libraries to a module like the following

[Adding Javascript to a D8 module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843)